# Sidekiq returning job id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, easypost

I'm have a `check_delivery` method which uses Sidekiq to call the EasyPost api gem.

```
  def check_delivery
    if tracking_number.present?
      EasypostWorker.perform_async(tracking_number)
    end
  end

class EasypostWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(tracking_number)
    EasyPost.api_key = Rails.application.secrets.easypost_api_key
    tracker = EasyPost::Tracker.create(tracking_code: tracking_number)
    tracker.status
  end
end
```

However this returns the 24 random char Sidekiq job id instead of the tracker status (ie, "out_for_delivery", "delivered", etc.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is because when calling `perform_async` it sends it to a background process and does not execute it immediately. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: In complement of @axsuul answer, you can use [sidekiq-status](https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status) to track your job progression and set up an ajax polling to display status to your users when your job is completed.

Answer (score 2):

The check_delivery method was calling the EasypostWorker, which returned the job id.

Apparently Sidekiq Workers don't return results like regular ruby classes and methods.

So I added a `status` attribute to my model and updated the attribute inside the Worker.